# Number in time periods

Tags: grammatical-number, time, comparisons

Why do we say "10 minutes or less" rather than "10 minutes or fewer?"

Answer (score 4):

You can use either, though *less* has the advantage.

There's a bit of a long-running argument on the use of *less* for countable items, but both sides agree that it can be used with real numbers, such as "8.3452 minutes" or "seven and a half minutes" or even "5 minutes" in a context where it's just by chance that our measurement comes up with a whole number of minutes.

That's assuming that you don't mean a whole-number of minutes only (i.e. it could be 3, or 5 or 9 minutes, but it couldn't be 5.94 minutes). Then you're back in the *less* / *fewer* debate, and probably better off siding with *fewer*. It would be an unusual case though, and probably need a less concise explanation.

When it is a countable case "Ten items or less" vs. "Ten items or fewer", it gets more controversial. Some maintain that when dealing with whole numbers, we can only use *fewer* because that does relate specifically to whole numbers. There's a long-standing use of *less* with countable cases though (at least as far back as about 888CE).

Comment: I think you're making the question more complicated than it is. We always use "fewer" with countable items, but you never see "I can finish the job in 3 hours or fewer," it's always "less." My guess is that this is because what is under discussion is a period of time, which is a singular concept.

Comment: It's not a singular concept, it's a non-discrete measurement. You can have half an hour. If you did want to mean "I'll finish this in 0, 1, 2 or 3 hours" then you'd use fewer. Pretty bizarre idea, but there's nothing ungrammatical about describing bizarre ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Because "less" has been used this way for 1000 years. In 1770, however, a certain Robert Baker wrote about his preference--that he uses "fewer" for number among things that are counted and "less" for quantity or amount among things that are measured. To cut the long story short, this became a rule, which, unfortunately, seems to have a million exceptions.

I urge you to watch this video from Merriam Webster. http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0013-fewer.htm?&t=1391533251